# Gerar Url atraves de formulario

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Tenho a seguinte url:

www.teste.com/username=xxxx

tenho que digita o nome do usario em xxxx, estou criando um form em html
com o campo username, quero que quando o usuario digita o nome dele neste form ele gere o link automatico por exemplo: se ele digita no campo o nome fernando
entao tem que ir para uma pagina que o link e o seguinte  www.teste.com/username=fernando estou ultiliziando JSF.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código que já tem?

Comment: Neste caso, você pode resolver esse problema apenas usando JavaScript, através do objeto location. Como exemplo estou lhe passando os seguintes links: - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

Você precisar usar a tag viewParam do jsf.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="username"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Existem diversar formas de você trabalhar com este valor recebido, aplicar conversores, validadores, carregar atributos do seu bean e etc. Isso vai depender da sua necessidade, mas uma pesquisa sobre viewParam no google vai te dar o caminho das pedras independente de qual seja seu desejo.